# Echarts : How can I use it to draw a Nightingale with describe two data?

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image]

Here is the map.I want it to describe two diffrent data. 
Use area to describe sum of orders ,and angle describe number of orders. 
Now I know type = "pie" and  roseType = true can draw Nightingale. 
But the data just can be only one, area and angle is the same percent. 
Help me ! thx!
(Forgive my pull English.Ծ‸ Ծ )

```
<style>

    .data-bac{box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #333;border-radius: 8px;background-color: #fff;}
    .data-img{width:700px;height: 482px;float:left;margin-bottom:20px;}
</style>
<div class='data-img data-bac' id='data-img'></div>
<script>
    var app = echarts.init(document.getElementById('data-img'));
    app.title = '嵌套环形图';
    var sum = [1200,1300,1400,1500] //here is the total money of area ,symbol for 苏州，常州，上海，无锡
    var option = {
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)"
        },
        legend: {
            orient: 'vertical',
            right:"8%",
            bottom:"8%",
            data: ["苏州","常州","无锡","上海"]
        },
        color:['#006699', '#00CC33','#000','#006600'],
        series: [{
            name:'注册用户数量的渠道分布',
            type:'pie',
            radius: ['30%', '55%'],
            roseType : true,
            data: [{
                value: 10,//here is the num of area
                name: '苏州'
            },{
                value: 20,//here is the num of area
                name: '常州'
            },{
                value: 30,//here is the num of area
                name: '无锡'
            },{
                value: 40,//here is the num of area
                name: '上海'
            }],
        }],
        backgroundColor:{color:"rgb(255,255,255)"}
    };
    // 使用刚指定的配置项和数据显示图表。
    app.setOption(option);

</script>
```

Comment: Could you add some example code if possible? Even the stuff used to generate the example.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the exact same thing, contacted the devs on GitHub, and was told that this was not possible with ECharts; it's simply not designed that way.

You have to pick between either `roseType: 'area'` and `roseType: 'radius'`.

[Documentation on roseType](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-pie.roseType)

Comment: I have no way to draw with ECharts.

Comment: Because what you want is not possible. You have to choose between two types of nightingale, area **or** radius, but you cannot combine them.

Comment: I've found that isn't possible.so I have to use some description in the name of area such as "上海,4单".

Answer (score 0):

```
  const option = {
        legend: {
            bottom: '0',
             width: "40%",
             left:"0",
             right:"0"
          },
           
        toolbox: {
            show: true,
          
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Nightingale Chart',
                type: 'pie',
                radius: [20, 60],
                center: ['50%', '50%'],
                roseType: 'area',
                labelLine: {
                    show: false
                  },
                     label: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'center'
                  },
                itemStyle: {
                    borderRadius: 2
                },
                data: [
                    { value: 24, name: 'Total raised', itemStyle: { color: '#79418A' } },
                    { value: 10, name: 'Resolved', itemStyle: { color: '#F06E99' } },
                    { value: 10, name: 'Pending', itemStyle: { color: '#F58773' } },
                    { value: 10, name: 'Escalated', itemStyle: { color: '#1AB89B' } },

                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

This will help You . you need to set false on label line and label